# The part /_rels/.rels does not have any content type ! Rule: Package require content types when retrieving a part from a package. [M.1.14]

Tags: java, excel

poi-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-3.16.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar

when I run the 'main' have some trouble

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {  
              POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();  
              EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);  
//            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile,  CipherAlgorithm.aes256, HashAlgorithm.md5, -1, -1, null);
              Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();  
              enc.confirmPassword("foobaa");  

               OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("e:/test/test.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);  
              //OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage. .create(FileOutputStream);  
              OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);  

              opc.save(os);  
              opc.close();  

              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("e:/test/test.xlsx");  
              fs.writeFilesystem(fos);  
              fos.close();  

            } catch (Exception e) {  
              e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
    }
```

Error message :org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: The part /_rels/.rels does not have any content type ! Rule: Package require content types when retrieving a part from a package. [M.1.14]

please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59378) may be related and its resolved by upgrading to a newer version of Xalan.

---

However, I encountered the bug when OPCPackage API modified my template input file unexpectedly.

TL;DR - try using the File or InputStream constructors instead of OPCPackage

I encountered this error with POI `4.1.2` when changing constructors based on the recommendation in the XSSFWorkbook constructor's JavaDoc:

```java
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(myFile))
```

to

```java
try (OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(myFile);
     XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg)) {
```

In my case, myFile is a template file and I don't expect it to be modified. However, on the second run of my code, I would get that error:

> The part /_rels/.rels does not have any content type ! Rule: Package require content types when retrieving a part from a package. [M.1.14]

I noticed that myFile was being modified and causing that error when I tried to read my template file (myFile) again. If you don't expect the file to be written, you can make it read-only a few different ways:

Changing to `OPCPackage.open(template, PackageAccess.READ)`, I get

> Operation not allowed, document open in read only mode!
> even though I'm not expecting that file to be modified.

With `chmod -w` (and the default PackageAccess.READ_WRITE) you can see where POI is trying to do the write.

When debugging, I noticed this TODO, which could be the bug? **org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument#write**

```java
    public final void write(OutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        OPCPackage p = getPackage();
        if(p == null) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already");
        }
        
        //force all children to commit their changes into the underlying OOXML Package
        // TODO Shouldn't they be committing to the new one instead?
        Set<PackagePart> context = new HashSet<>();
        onSave(context);
        context.clear();

        //save extended and custom properties
        getProperties().commit();

        p.save(stream);
    }
```

You may also want to try using `revert()` instead of `close()` in `OPCPackage` if you don't want it to modify the file.